# IdeaVim: Enable Navigation Keys in ReadOnly Files?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

## How can Vim navigation keys be enabled in IntelliJ while viewing ReadOnly files?

For example, you navigate to the source code of a function which is in a jar file. Then the h, j, k, l, and /find keys are ignored.

How can these vim navigation keys be enabled when viewing read only files in IntelliJ 15?

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by the bug [VIM-970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-970) in IdeaVim. Unfortunately, there is no known workaround yet.

---

Edit: It was fixed from the build 293 (>= #293). It only works with the recent EAP versions of IntelliJ 15 and other IDEs.